# Xamarin.Android ViewPager memory leaks

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android

We do an application that shows users their deals per week. There are all weeks from 2016 till 2040 year. For this we use ViewPager that get list of DateTime elements. Yes, it has a lot of elements. And due to DateTime element fragment in ViewPager create expandableListView. We supposed that ViewPager can reuse elements or at least delete elements that it does not use right now.

May be in original Android this thing has place, but in our project we have memory leaks. I mean this - we change fragment, memory increases AND NEVER decreases! We have created special single thread that call GC.Collect every 4 (four) seconds, but it is very bad idea. Unfortunately, in other way, memory will increase more and more.

And when we call notifyDataSetChanged() we get memory leaks too.

Please help us. Can you suggest another and good solution of it? (if code is needed I will show, but please say what exactly code you need)